# failing to get attribute from a xml in a asp file

Tags: asp-classic

I have been trying to get one of the attributes from the following xml,

```
<getAtt MapReady="0" QueryTime="0" t="17" tt="15" pcheck="1" Startval="1" AutoNextStres="171" TC="171" q=+(A%3a(64))+AND+C%3a0+AND+((((BODY%3asujit)+OR+(BODY%3asujit*))+AND++(+(ICAL3%3a1+)+AND+(+(ICAL4%3a1+)+OR+(ICAL4%3a3+)+OR+(ICAL4%3a6+)++)++)))&amp;start=1&amp;rows=40" LogID="1664" ErrorCode=""></<getAtt>
```

From the xml specified,i have to get "t" attribute.And this xml is saving in a variable in a asp file.Please suggest me hot to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.

You could manually split the string and parse it manually, or, you can use a 3rd party XML parser such as [Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - i'll recommend the latter.

First you need to prep the getAtt node as a basic XML document with the relevant parent node etc (main thing you need is a root node) and then open that XML document in MSXML2. Once open you can set the root and loop through each getAtt node within.

Here is an example:

```
<%
    ''#### Define the XML to parse
    dim TestXML, oXML, oNode, sValue 
    TestXML = TestXML & "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbcrlf
    TestXML = TestXML & "<wrapperNode>" & vbcrlf
    TestXML = TestXML & "<getAtt MapReady=""0"" QueryTime=""0"" t=""17"" tt=""15"" pcheck=""1"" Startval=""1""></getAtt>" & vbcrlf
    TestXML = TestXML & "</wrapperNode>" & vbcrlf

    ''#### Ready the XML Parser
    Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")

    ''#### Load the XML
    oXML.LoadXML(TestXML)

    ''#### Set the root (so we can easily get a collection of nodes)
    Set oRoot = oXML.selectSingleNode("//wrapperNode")

    ''#### Loop through each node and echo out the value of the "t" attribute
    For Each oNode In oRoot.childNodes
      response.Write oNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("t").Text
    Next 

    ''#### Cleanup
    Set oXML = Nothing 
%>
```

Comment: Why `.Attributes.getNamedItem("t").Text` instead of the simpler and more standard `.getAttribute("t")`?